# C++ _byteswap_ulong was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, hex, endianness

when I try to compile my program I get this error:

```
error: ‘_byteswap_ushort’ was not declared in this scope
long lNum = (long)_byteswap_ushort(iNum);
```

this is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   long inputNum;
   cout << "Input number:\n";
   cin >> inputNum;

   long Num = (long)_byteswap_ulong(iNum);
   stringstream oss;
   oss << hex << Num;
   string mystring = oss.str();

   return 0;
}
```

I thought that including stdlib should solve the problem. Is there any other library I should include?

The program is compiled with:

```
g++ -m32 -o output32 prog.cpp
```

Comment: Vendor defined function (starts with an _);  MS VC extension.  Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx

Comment: example from msdn, gives me the same error

Comment: Are you compiling this on a Windows system? With Microsoft headers?

Comment: no, i am using linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use a function specific to MS Visual C++ compiler, which is not available in GCC. Use an appropriate [GCC builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) instead.

Seems like `uint32_t __builtin_bswap32(uint32_t x)` would be appropriate in this case.

Another option, if you wanted a portable solution, would be to use something like [Boost Endian library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html).